# XSD w/ Java Validator "minOccurs" not working as expected

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I'm working on adding an XSD validator feature to a tool I created at work. The tool actually generates an XML with very strict formatting. The format of the XML is defined in a mapping document and there is also an XSD schema.

What I want is to add the ability for a user to quickly validate an XML they create in the tool. I have added all of the code for this validation to occur. Unfortunately, I am having a couple of unexpected problems.

Specifically in one section of the XML are about 20 tags. These tags will not always appear in an XML file, many are optional. I need the validation to ignore the optional tags if they are not present - Instead the validator returns an error EVEN IF I set the "Minoccurs" value to 0.

Here is my validator code:

```
package misc;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;
import javax.xml.XMLConstants;

import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import javax.xml.validation.Schema;
import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory;
import javax.xml.validation.Validator;

import org.xml.sax.SAXException;


public class XMLValidation {


    public static JFileChooser uploadFile;


    public static boolean validateXMLSchema(String xsdPath, String xmlPath){

        try{

            SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);

            Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new File(xsdPath));
            Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
            validator.validate(new StreamSource(new File(xmlPath)));


        }catch(IOException | SAXException e){


            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());

            return false;

        }   

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No errors detected!");

        return true;

    }

    public static void uploadFile(){

        boolean uploadApproval = false;

        while(uploadApproval==false){//While upload approval has not been given..

            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();//Creates a new object of the JFileChooser class. 

            uploadFile = chooser;//Saves the upload file variable as the chooser response. 

            FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("XML Files", "xml");
            //Sets the allowed file formats for upload. 

            chooser.setFileFilter(filter);//Activates the created file filter.

            chooser.setDialogTitle("Select a Camt54 file to validate");//Sets the title bar text. 

            //Completes once the user clicks ok. 
            int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(chooser);//
            if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                uploadApproval=true;
            }else{
                System.exit(0);
            }

            }
        }

}
```

I can't share my entire XSD schema because of security. I attempted to take out a portion that would illustrate what I mean:

```
<xs:complexType name="CntsRecord1">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="test1" type="ISODateTime"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="test2" type="ISODateTime"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="test3" type="ISODateTime"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="test4" type="type4"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="test5" type="Max35Text"/>    
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="test6" type="Max140Text"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="test7" type="type5"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0"  name="Test" type="Max140Text"/>    

        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
```

As you can see, the "minOccurs" for all of these values is set at 0, so they should not return an error.

Once I run this code however I will get back an error that the element "Test" is expected. (Assuming all the others are present).

Is there some difficulty in running the validation with the xsd and using minimum values of 0?

Here is the error I get back from the validator:

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a:Invalid content was found starting with element 'Test10'. One of {"urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt:054:001:04:"Test}' is expected.
```

Here is the example from my XML file:

```
-<Cnts>

<Test1>2016-08-18T09:51:41</Test1>

<Test2>2016-08-18T09:51:41</Test2>

<Test3>2016-08-18T09:51:41</Test3>

<Test4>PAPER</Test4>

<Test5>2016-08-18T09:51:41</Test1>

<Test6>2016-08-18T09:51:41</Test2>

<Test7>2016-08-18T09:51:41</Test3>

<Test10>PAPER</Test4>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show us the full error message and the XML document that fails validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*First off, your XML and your XSD do not agree on the capitalization of the `test` elements, and your XML is not well-formed.*

However, assuming that those issues are merely artifacts of your attempt to sanitize your sensitive data to create an example that you can safely post, **your actual question boils down to understanding this error message:**

> cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'Test10'. One of {"urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt:054:001:04:"Test}' is **expected**.

Yes, since `Test` is declared with `minOccurs="0"`, it is indeed optional.  The error is not saying otherwise.  It is saying that the parser has encountered an element after successfully parsing `Test7`, and that element is not what it ***expected***.  It **expected** an element that follows `Test7` to be `Test` because according to your XSD, that's the only element that ***may*** (not *must*) appear there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It does appear that the same error message is generated when I set the "minOccurs" to 1 however. So are you saying that this is unavoidable? That regardless of the minimum occurs it's still going to expect a tag to appear?

Comment: You're still tripping up over a key distinction between the ***requiredness*** that is represented by the occurrence constraints and the ***diagnostic message*** that is trying to help you understand what ***might*** validly come next rather than the bad tag that it found did come next.

Comment: Maybe it would help if I paraphrase the message:  *`Test10` shouldn't be here.  If something's going to appear here, it has to be `Test`.*  Yes, this is true whether `Test` is optional or required because either way `Test10` shouldn't be there and the expectation for the next element after `Test7` (given that *something* is there) is that it must be `Test`.

Comment: So what your saying is the sequence is the problem, not that test is missing on it's own? The validator doesn't care that test isn't there, it only cares that some Element is out of sequence? Do you know if any good way to remedy this or should we just not validate that complex type where the elements are optional?

Comment: It looks like the problem may be because I used xs:sequence. Do you know of another alternative such as xs:choice that would work? I actually just tired xs:all and it still did not work.

Comment: No, I'm not saying that `xs:sequence` is the problem at all.  I'm saying that there is no problem; both validation and the error message are correct.  Your XML has an element, `Test10`, that appears nowhere in your XSD, so it is invalid, and the diagnostic message your receive is entirely appropriate as I've explained.

Comment: I finally figured it out per your comments. The problem was that there were far more tags beyond "Test10". I had neglected to add them to the mapping until I figured this problem out - Turns out that was the problem. I added all the missing elements and now it works as expected. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is certainly more up to date than this, but if you care to go back to good old Xerces, Xerces validation seems to have no problems with minOccurs=0. This link gives a tutorial: http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2004/09/15/schema-validation.html

Example code:

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

    System.setProperty("javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory", "org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl");
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    factory.setValidating(true);
    factory.setAttribute("http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxp/properties/schemaLanguage", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
    factory.setAttribute("http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxp/properties/schemaSource", schemaUrl);
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Validator handler = new Validator();
    builder.setErrorHandler(handler);
    builder.parse(IOUtils.toInputStream(xmlString));
    if (handler._validationError) {
        StringBuilder xmsg = new StringBuilder();
        for (SAXParseException exception : handler.getExceptions()) {
            xmsg.append(exception.getMessage());
            xmsg.append("\n");
        }
        //show xmsg in your dialog
    }
```

Comment: I may end up giving this a shot. I'll let you know how it goes.